# EJB 3.0 webservice in weblogic 10.3.3.4

Tags: eclipse, web-services, oracle, ejb-3.0, weblogic

I am trying to create a EJB 3.0 session bean with methods exposed as webservice.I am using Eclipse and my weblogic server is integreated and is there a tutorial of sorts to create a sample webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the docs that have an example of an EJB 3.0 web service?
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13758/jws.htm#i246190